# Set variable as value of a column in PDO query

Tags: variables, pdo

- When should i set a variable as value of a column on PDO query?
- What is the difference between the codes below?

:

```
$stmtPG = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE entry_type = 'post'");    
$total = $stmtPG->fetchColumn();
```

And:

```
$type = 'post';
$stmtPG = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE entry_type = '$type'");    
$total = $stmtPG->fetchColumn();
```

The values on the query will not come from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works out to be the same, whichever way you  run it.

But...

Ideally you'd want to use positional parameters and prepared statements...  This should get you going, it is partial copy/paste from the do-it-all function I wrote that I use everywhere.  Strongly encourage you to write your own or find one (write once, include many, fix once when needed!).

```
    $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $hostname . ';port=' . $dbPort . ';dbname=' . $dbName . ';charset=utf8', $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
    $dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query="SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE entry_type = ?");
    $parameters=array("post");
    $result = $dbconn->prepare($query);
    $result->execute($arr);
    if(!$result){
      die("Query error:".$dbconn->errorInfo());
    }
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $dataRetrieved[] = $row;
    }
```

Edit -

The questioner asks in a comment below - "Some people said to me that it don't need to put placeholders if the value is not coming from the client-side. And you did it. why? It seems that every person have their own opinion... "

Well... True.  If you are running a static query, you don't need to parameterize or use prepared statements, etc. because you are in full control over what is being used/queried,etc.

But back to the "write once, include everywhere, fix in one place when needed" ... if I use my function or class everywhere, it needs to be able to handle queries that use user-generated input as well as queries that are static and known-safe.  So things always get parameterized, even if not strictly needed.

Comment: Some people said to me that it don't need to put `placeholders` if the value is not coming from the client-side. And you did it. why? It seems that every person have their own opinion...

Comment: @Susi - correct, if you are controlling input, you don't need to parameterize and prepare a statement to prevent against SQL injection.   I'll edit my answer to including some good reasons too anyway.